# Nested Classes and Inheritance C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, nested-class

this is rather a strange question but I am using nested classes to make property-like functionality in c++.
I also made these work as ReadOnly by making the nested class's assignment operator protected and the host class a `Friend` of the nested class.
Unfortunately it seems that any inheriting class (with `: public BaseClass`) still cant access the nested class's assignment operator.

I dont know if it matters but I did put the `Friend` in the public section of the class.

Anyone know how I can fix this? (or hack it) Thanks

EDIT: code example added

```
#define ReadOnlyProperty(type,name,parent) \
protected: \
class name : public PropertyBase<type> \
{ \
    parent* This; \
public: \
    friend class parent; \
    name(parent* instance) { This = instance; } \
protected: \
    void operator=(type value) {Set(value);} \
    void Set(type value); \
    type Get() const; \
}; \
public: name name; \
friend class name; \
private:
```

Base class:

```
class Object
{
ReadOnlyProperty(char,Type,Object);

public:

Object() : Type(this) {}
};
```

Inheriting class

```
class A : public Object
{
public:
A() {Type = 'A';}
};
```

i get an error on the Type = 'A'

Comment: You can't automatically make all inherited classes friends. If you put a piece of code, we can see what a good workaround might look like.

Answer (score 6):

Friendliness is not inherited.

It's not clear what the best solution is; perhaps declare the nested class in the protected section of the base class, and make its members public?  That way no friendship is needed, but stuff from outside the class hierarchy won't be able to fiddle with it.

Comment: I would never usually upvote such a short and non-detailed answer, but there are many reasons that this one deserves it for _this_ question. I can't be bothered to list them. And I know you know them anyway.

Comment: +1 I actually love answers like this. The only reason I don't post them very often is that for some reason people like reading more words than they need to, and my answer ends up getting downvoted as a result.

Comment: Well, it isn't an answer to the question (How to fix this?). But answering this question requires a redesign, I think, so there is no straight-forward solution. Is there?

Answer (score 0):

and it does not matter which section you put the friend declaration.

perhaps, instead, put the inner class in the protected section, and make its interfaces public.

Comment: Please write in complete sentences.

Comment: Putting the class in protected has no effect.